# Shuffling and hiding views specified by parameters

Tags: javascript, angular.js

In my Angular app, users click on different icons. When a user clicks on respective icon, I can show the icons gallery, as well `shuffle` the view.

Apart from this shuffling functionality, I need to `hide` whatever other `gallery` is already open.

For that, I've written the following function, but, I think it could use some refactoring.

```
$scope.galleryMenu = function ( GalleryType ) {

            var hideGallery = (function (type) {

                return {

                    galleryVideoShow : function () {

                        //closing others
                        $scope.contractorShow = false;
                        $scope.galleryPhotoShow = false;
                    },

                    contractorShow : function () {
                        //closing others
                        $scope.galleryPhotoShow = false;
                        $scope.galleryVideoShow = false;

                    },

                    galleryPhotoShow : function () {

                       //closing others
                        $scope.contractorShow = false;
                        $scope.galleryVideoShow = false;

                    }

                }

            })();

            $scope.$watch('viewProjectInfo', function ( newValue, oldValue ) {


                if(!newValue) return;

                $scope.photos = $scope.viewProjectInfo.ImagePaths;

                $scope[GalleryType] = !$scope[GalleryType];
                $scope.shownGallery =  GalleryType;

                hideGallery[GalleryType](); //manually close other open gallery

                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');



            });



        };
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things that could be improved:

---

You have quite a lot of empty white lines, and extraneous space:

> ```
> return {
>
>     galleryVideoShow : function () {
>
>         //closing others
>         $scope.contractorShow = false;
>         $scope.galleryPhotoShow = false;
>     },
>
>     contractorShow : function () {
>
>     // ...
> ```

This block, for example, without extraneous whitespace, would look like:

```
return {
    galleryVideoShow: function(){
        $scope.contractorShow,
        $scope.galleryPhotoShow = false;
    },
    contractorShow: function(){

    //...
```

---

> ```
>         var hideGallery = (function (type) {
>
>             return {
>
>                 galleryVideoShow : function () {
>
>                     //closing others
>                     $scope.contractorShow = false;
>                     $scope.galleryPhotoShow = false;
>                 },
>
>                 contractorShow : function () {
>                     //closing others
>                     $scope.galleryPhotoShow = false;
>                     $scope.galleryVideoShow = false;
>
>                 },
>
>                 galleryPhotoShow : function () {
>
>                    //closing others
>                     $scope.contractorShow = false;
>                     $scope.galleryVideoShow = false;
>
>                 }
>
>             }
>
>         })();
> ```

There's no reason to assign `hideGallery` like that.

It'd be better as a plain object.

```
var hideGallery = {
        galleryVideoShow: function(){
            //closing others
            $scope.contractorShow,
            $scope.galleryPhotoShow = false;
        },
        contractorShow: function(){
            $scope.galleryPhotoShow,
            $scope.galleryVideoShow = false;
        },
        galleryPhotoShow: function(){
            $scope.contractorShow,
            $scope.galleryVideoShow = false;
        }
}
```

Which would be better called something like `GALLERY_EFFECTS`, and kept as a constant.

Also note that for each function in `hideGallery`, the comment `//closing others` was present, it's only part of what the functions do, and would be better off at the root of `hideGallery` in a more expanded version.

---

> ```
>        $scope.$watch('viewProjectInfo', function ( newValue, oldValue ) {
>
>
>             if(!newValue) return;
>
>             $scope.photos = $scope.viewProjectInfo.ImagePaths;
>
>             $scope[GalleryType] = !$scope[GalleryType];
>             $scope.shownGallery =  GalleryType;
>
>             hideGallery[GalleryType](); //manually close other open gallery
>
>             $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
>
>
>
>         });
>
>
>
>     };
> ```

- Why are there so many empty lines at the bottom? (*six, I counted*) They just look poorly formatted, or like missing code.
- You should wrap your conditionals in brackets, because untold circumstances can happen.
- You should spread the `.animate` call over a multiple lines, as you're building an object inside the function call.

```
   $scope.$watch('viewProjectInfo', function(newValue, oldValue){
       if (!newValue){ return };
       $scope.photos = $scope.viewProjectInfo.ImagePaths;

       $scope[GalleryType] = !$scope[GalleryType];
       $scope.shownGallery = GalleryType;

       hideGallery[GalleryType]();

       $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(document).height()
       }, 'slow');
   });
```